# Why do I only get one beacon even when using multiple BLE filters?

Tags: android, filter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I want to receive beacons from 2 BLE devices. I know their Bluetooth addresses. I have created a filter list like so:

```
private List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>(); // Global in actual code

ScanFilter filter1 = new ScanFilter.Builder()
    .setDeviceAddress(bluetoothAddress1).build();

ScanFilter filter2 = new ScanFilter.Builder()
    .setDeviceAddress(bluetoothAddress2).build();

filters.add(filter1);
            
filters.add(filter2);
```

and call it with

```
mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
```

(settings and callback have been defined elsewhere and work correctly).

If I print the filters list, I can see both my filters so I know they're there. If I comment out one of the filters, I will correctly receive packets from the other beacon only (this is true no matter which filter I comment out). However, if I leave both filters uncommented, then I only ever receive packets from the second device.

Why is it that scanning with filters only ever gives me packets from one device, not from multiple?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put it inside a method.
The below code works for me:

```
private List<ScanFilter> scanFilters() {

    List<ScanFilter> list = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();

    ScanFilter scanFilterMAC00 = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("The MAC Address of the device").build();
    ScanFilter scanFilterMAC01 = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("The MAC Address of the device").build();
    ScanFilter scanFilterMAC02 = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("The MAC Address of the device").build();
    ScanFilter scanFilterMAC03 = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("The MAC Address of the device").build();
    ScanFilter scanFilterMAC04 = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("The MAC Address of the device").build();
    ScanFilter scanFilterMAC05 = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("The MAC Address of the device").build();
    // and so on....


    list.add(scanFilterMAC00);
    list.add(scanFilterMAC01);
    list.add(scanFilterMAC02);
    list.add(scanFilterMAC03);
    list.add(scanFilterMAC04);
    list.add(scanFilterMAC05);
    // and so on.... When you finish, just return the list.

    return list;
}
```

And then, the `startScanning()` method:

```
public void startScanning() {
        ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER).build();
        btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        btScanner.startScan(scanFilters(), settings, scanCallback);
    }
}
```

`btScanner`is an instance of class `BluetoothLeScanner`.

That's it. As I said, it works fine for me, returns every MAC Address I add to the methods list.

Comment: Right, except there is no need to involve a method. Checked with two setDeviceName().